# Method for constructing a gate

Tags: boolean-logic

I'm trying to construct a multiplex gate. It has two inputs, and one selector. I got as far as 
the truth table.

```
A  |  B  |  Sel  | Out
0     0      1      0
0     1      1      0
1     0      1      1
1     1      1      1
0     0      0      0
0     1      0      1
1     0      0      0
1     1      0      1
```

And this is where my method fails. I've constructed simpler gates such as AND, and OR. Those were so simple I didn't need an articulate method. I went to wikipedia to see if I could get
a method. Instead I only discovered which gates I need to construct the circuit. For my goals, this misses the point. More important to me is the method that arrives at the answer, rather than the answer itself. I know I need to use DeMorgan's Laws, but fall down when trying to come up with specifics. Any hints would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Keith's answer, here's the Karnaugh map for your truth table:

```
             AB
         00 01 11 10
         ___________
sel  0  | 0  1  1  0
     1  | 0  0  1  1
```

This is created by grouping A and B, and then making a matrix of the outputs for any given input. Note the column headings do not count in binary, rather they are more like a grey code, having only one transition between each column.

Now that's done, you can write an equation that ORs together terms that cover all the 1s in the Karnaugh map.

On the Karnaugh map, it's pretty easy to see terms that cover multiple 1s. For example, the term `B.sel'` (B and not sel) covers both the 1's in the top row.

That combined with `A.sel` for the 1's in the bottom row gives the equation

```
output = B.sel' + A.sel
```

This works out at 4 gates, including the NOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), which will help you pick the gates you need to implement your function.